Matching whitespace lazy or greedy - which one performs better?
I am building a name matching regex. Since a lot of those names have spaces in them, but we still want to match cases where more than one space is being used, we're not just using a single, regular whitespace character.
One optimization I heard about is making the whitespace matching in between words (like the space in the name "Alex Smith") lazy, instead of greedy.
I know what the difference between lazy and greedy matching is, but I don't understand how it would have an effect on matching whitespace.
Here is what I got right now:
Alex\s+?Smith

Are there any performance benefits to actually using the lazy modifier on the \s+ parts in this case? I couldn't find any good material on this specific case of matching just whitespace between words.
Any help would be appreciated!

You can always perf-test by yourself on different browsers. PS: why you hardcoded alex and smith in your string? I'm not sure to completely understand your question regarding names and spaces... There are too many variations of names in the world... Also, what is about those academic titles again? Could you provide some matching samples and the expected?

it was just an example. the final regex gets generated by our engine, but it's based on a list of names people enter that they want to match against. some names have aliases, so "Dr. Smith" is the same as "Alex Smith" or "Dr. Alex Smith". The title was just an example, it could be a name with multiple parts like "markus peter parker"
i did a little performance test and there wasn't a discernible difference, but it could've been my small sample size - hence the question.

@WiktorStribiżew I don't see how the duplicate you proposed answers the question about performance

There is no difference in outcome between lazy and greedy repetition of whitespaces when the next character is a non-whitespace. Since you don't need the extra attempts when backtracking, you could even use a possessive repetition \s++ if JavaScript would support it; I recommend to keep the modifier simple and greedy: \s+.

thanks! is the behavior of when and how lazy matching works documented somewhere? I couldn't find a detailed explanation of when to use it, exactly, and why.

I've always liked https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, but surely there's other good tutorials that I don't know

So could one say that since we're matching against a single "character" (not quite, but let's simplify it), lazy matching is never required in that sense?
Like, if I say "Hello+?" can match Hellooooo, I can just leave the lazy modifier since there's no way it will match anything else anyhow?
